# ngClick evaluated against scope instead of isolateScope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am experiencing a problem with a directive which seems initially pretty easy to write. From what I understood my problem is related with the scope against which an expression is evaluated.

There is also a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKHn5CnXD55f1wmZhRgF) with a demo.

I have got the following JavaScript code with a controller and a directive:

```
angular.module('parentGet', [])
  .controller('Parent', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = function() {
      alert('hello world');
    };
  })
  .directive('child', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        fn: '&'
      },
      link: function($scope) {
        $scope.fn2 = function() {
          $scope.fn();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

This code is used from the following HTML

```
<body ng-controller="Parent">
  <div child fn="foo" ng-click="fn2()">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I click on the div, the ng-click is properly triggered however when I set a breakpoint inside angular.js file ([line 22949 of the 1.3.8 version](https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.3.8/angular.js#L22949)), I can see that the ng-click is evaluated against the Parent controller scope and not against the child directive isolated scope.

Any suggestion to make that code work ?

**EDIT**

To be more specific the problem I have is that the fn2 is never called which seems pretty weird in my case. 
The ng-click tries to evaluate the *fn2()* expression again the controller scope which does not have any fn2 function which leads angular to take the *noop* function.

Comment: Yes this is the default behavior.

Comment: I've updated the answer for your edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior. From the angular docs:

> When the user clicks the x in the dialog, the directive's close
>   function is called, thanks to ng-click. This call to close on the
>   isolated scope actually evaluates the expression hideDialog() in the
>   context of the original scope, thus running Controller's hideDialog
>   function.

See it in here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

**Answer to edited question**

The thing you are expecting that ng-click will call `fn2()` of directive function will again not be possible. Since angular will again evaluate that function call with parent controller scope. So change your code to this:

```
.directive('child', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        fn: '&'
      },
      link: function($scope, element) {
        element.on('click', $scope.fn2);

        $scope.fn2 = function() {
          $scope.fn();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

And change your html snippet to:

```
<body ng-controller="Parent">
  <div child fn="foo">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I edited my previous post since the problem is not that the function called is evaluated in the wrong scope but that the fn2 is never evaluated since there is no fn2 in the controller scope.